# Why does \label create an undesired white space after \phantomsubcaption?

Tags: cross-referencing, subcaption

Usually `\label` does not create any white spaces.
However, It creates an white space when `\label` is used after `\phantomsubcaption` from `subcaption` package.

- Why?
- How can I get rid of this white space?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\section{a}
a\label{sec:a}b% no white space between `a' and `b'

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  {a\phantomsubcaption\label{fig:a}}%
  {b\phantomsubcaption\label{fig:b}}
  \caption{With label}% undesired white space between `a' and `b'
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  {a\phantomsubcaption}%
  {b\phantomsubcaption}
  \caption{Without label}% no white space between `a' and `b'
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If one drops the relevant `\phantomsubcaption` statements in the `\label`ed figure `environment` there is no additional whitespace. However, the labels `fig:a` and `fig:b` are unknown outside. Why do you want to have such an arrangement? Perhaps it could be achieved with other methods.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt This should interest you. Thanks for all your work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an error in line 87 of `subcaption.sty`:

```
 87 \newcommand*\subcaption@label{
 88   \caption@withoptargs\subcaption@@label}
```

At the end of line 87, after the brace, a `%` is missing.

If you add to your preamble, after loading `subcaption`,

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\subcaption@label{%
  \caption@withoptargs\subcaption@@label}
\makeatother
```

the output will be correct, without any spurious space.

Please, make this known to the package maintainer.

Comment: @krnk He's active here, so he should already be aware of the problem, but I'll ping him

Comment: I'm deeply sorry. (Shame on me.) I filled the issue https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/tickets/20/ but totally forgot to fix this one. I have done so just now, and will upload the fixed version to CTAN tomorrow. If waiting is not an option grab the actual files from https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/code/HEAD/tree/branches/3.3/tex/

Comment: I have just done the CTAN upload (caption package bundle release 2016-02-21), so the update should be available on CTAN, and for TeXlive, MikTeX and other TeX distributions within the next days.

Answer (score 6):

`\phantomsubcaption` and `\phantomcaption` do not have any arguments. Further, they do not generate any output, but give you an anchor for a `\label` command which can be placed afterwards. In addition, it increases the sub-figure and/or sub-table counter. It is noteworthy that – just like `\subcaption` – the `\phantomsubcaption` command must be applied inside its *own group*, *box*, or *environment*.

Here in your code, as you are not using any `subfigure` environment, you can put `\phantomsubcaption` inside braces like `{\phantomsubcaption}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\section{a}
a\label{sec:a}b% no white space between `a' and `b'

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  {a{\phantomsubcaption}\label{fig:a}}%
  {b{\phantomsubcaption}\label{fig:b}}
  \caption{With label}% undesired white space between `a' and `b'
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  {a\phantomsubcaption}%
  {b\phantomsubcaption}
  \caption{Without label}% no white space between `a' and `b'
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Or you can also use `\ignorespaces` like

```
{a\phantomsubcaption\ignorespaces\label{fig:a}}%
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\section{a}
a\label{sec:a}b% no white space between `a' and `b'

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  {a\phantomsubcaption\ignorespaces\label{fig:a}}%
  {b\phantomsubcaption\label{fig:b}}
  \caption{With label}% undesired white space between `a' and `b'
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  {a\phantomsubcaption}%
  {b\phantomsubcaption}
  \caption{Without label}% no white space between `a' and `b'
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works, because `\ignorespaces` triggers the expansion of `\label` and so it eats the spurious space.

Comment: @krnk Please see the edit.