# Unwanted space with label in subfigure (subcaption) environment

Tags: spacing, captions, subcaption

I am tiling images in latex using subcaption's subfigure environment. And because I'm taking things very precisely, I tried to calculate exact spacings, so everything aligns nicely, as in the following example:
[image: Five images nicely tiled in pdflatex]

However, I want each of the small figures to have proper labels etc. So what I'm doing is: adding a phantomsubcaption and then adding the label. But as soon as I add one or more labels, things look weird like this:
[image: Five images not so nicely tiled in pdflatex]

The phantomsubcaptions do not seem to be the problem. I would like to understand, where this "negative spacing" or whatever this is comes from and how I could avoid it. My MWE is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\newlength{\picutreHeightFramed}
\setlength{\picutreHeightFramed}{.3746397694524496\textwidth}
\newlength{\pictureDeltaX}
\setlength{\pictureDeltaX}{-1pt+.0198\picutreHeightFramed}

Do not understand.
\begin{figure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{.495\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \end{subfigure}\hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.495\textwidth}%
                \includegraphics[width=.49\linewidth]{example-image-b}\phantomsubcaption\hfill
                \includegraphics[width=.49\linewidth]{example-image-c}\phantomsubcaption
                \vspace{\pictureDeltaX}
                \includegraphics[width=.49\linewidth]{example-image-b}\phantomsubcaption\hfill
                \includegraphics[width=.49\linewidth]{example-image-c}\phantomsubcaption\label{fig:whyyyyy}%
        \end{subfigure}%
        \caption{Testy test.}
        \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The newlength and setlength commands just help me to calculate proper lengths for the small tiled images. I already tried fiddling around with those comment marks at the end of the line and removing/adding breaks, but this seems to be another kind of issue.

Comment: It would seem as if the error egreg explained [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161221/30280) still hasn't been fixed by the package maintainer.

Comment: I'm deeply sorry. (Shame on me.) I filled the issue https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/tickets/20/ but totally forgot to fix this one. I have done so just now, and will upload the fixed version to CTAN tomorrow. If waiting is not an option grab the actual files from https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/code/HEAD/tree/branches/3.3/tex/

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the fix, this is really great!

Comment: I have just done the CTAN upload (caption package bundle release 2016-02-21), so the update should be available on CTAN, and for TeXlive, MikTeX and other TeX distributions within the next days.

Comment: BTW: Since you are inside a `subfigure` you could use `\phantomcaption` instead of `\phantomsubcaption`. (But using `\phantomsubcaption` does not make any harm, in fact both commands are exactly the same inside a `subfigure` or `subtable` environment.)